# Value in cell is changing after a message box

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code

```
Sub errors()

Dim wsd As Worksheet

Set wsd = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Forc

        If Len([F4]) <> 4 Then
            [F4] = MsgBox("add values")

        End If

    End With


End Sub
```

My code reads that if in cell F4, if the number of digits is not 4 to display an error message. The error message displays properly but when I press "ok" on the message box, the value in F4 changes to 1. I do not want it to change to 1. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: It happens because MsgBox returns a value and you assign it to [F4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code below:

```
Sub errors()
Dim wsd As Worksheet
Set wsd = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Forc
        If Len([F4]) <> 4 Then
            MsgBox ("add values")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Any questions or concerns, feel free to let me know. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Much appreciated and learned something new about MsgBox's

Answer (score 1):

It is doing this because you're saying:

```
[F4] = MsgBox("add values")
```

... meaning setting equal the range `F4` the value of the `MsgBox`. The `MsgBox` returning `vbOk` (enumerate value corresponding to 1), the value is set to 1.

You just need to write:

```
MsgBox("add values")
```

Comment: Actually, `MsgBox` function returns `VbMsgBoxResult`. If no enumeration values of `VbMsgBoxStyle` were provided, the default return value is vbOk, which equals `1` which equals to True. So, please, don't confuse people with incorrect explanation.

Comment: @JohnyL added your explanation to the question, thanks for correcting it. I thought it was just returning True. P.s. I invite you to read SO's [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), especially the section about unfriendly language.

Answer (score 0):

Dont equel the range [F4] to your message Box, that's why its taking the return value

```
Sub errors()

Dim wsd As Worksheet

Set wsd = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Forc

        If Len([F4]) <> 4 Then
            MsgBox("add values")

        End If

    End With


End Sub
```